# How to write find command to delete 7 days older files with selected JPGs ?

Tags: linux

I use Linux on Centos
And I need to remove the JPG in a file for more than 7 days.
But can't delete the JPG of the main directory

example: find /users/mac/desktop/test/*

Will output

```
/users/mac/desktop/test/test.jpg
/users/mac/desktop/test/test01
/users/mac/desktop/test/test01/test01.jpg
/users/mac/desktop/test/test02
/users/mac/desktop/test/test02/test02.jpg
```

But I only need delete this two .jpg

```
/users/mac/desktop/test/test01/test01.jpg
/users/mac/desktop/test/test02/test02.jpg
```

Comment: `find /users/mac/desktop/test/*.jpg |grep 0`

Comment: I have searched for similar problems, but none of them match my

Comment: @treyBake 
Hello, actually my file name may not be fixed. I can't use the name as a condition.

Comment: I'm confused now :s

Comment: also just noticed this may be better for unix SE

Comment: this is not a question about programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to remove the JPG in a file for more than 7 days.  But can't delete the JPG of the main directory

```
find /users/mac/desktop/test -mtime +7 -mindepth 2 -type f -name '*.jpg' -delete
```

- `-mtime +7` the modification time of the file is older then 7 days
- `-mindepth 2` ignore the "main directory"
- `-type f` only files
- `-name '*.jpg'` only jpg files
- `-delete` delete them

Answer (score -2):

```
find /users/mac/desktop/test/*/*
```

Comment: Why `find` then, when you can `echo` or `printf "%n"` ?

Comment: Because we need, for example, the "-mtime" option. My fix was to add the second /* at the end, so that it doesn't match JPG files in the parent directory.